# How to create dinamic model from request User

Tags: django, django-models

i'would like create dinamic model in Django with the request user.
Example the user need create 4 leves for categories for products or 10,20, etc...
how i create this tables(models).
in a form the user write numbers of levels categories and next i should create this tables with this structure:

```
________________________
name| description |state|
_________________________
firs| first categ | 1   |
....| ............|.....|
```

and this for each level.

but i dont know how create this please any suggest or idea.. sorry but dont write code but i dont know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursive relationships.

In your model (Table) you could to add a field named 'parent_1'. Ex.:

```
parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
```

This fields is related with itself and can be null

Comment: sorry but i dont understand about this "recursive relationship"..maybe you can say a example or link for  check this on django

Comment: Check this link:
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/]